# Refactor array for loop result

Tags: coffeescript

```
types = [
    { name: "Feature"}
    { name: "Enhancement"}
    { name: "Bug"}
    { name: "Spike"}
  ]

buildIndex = (source, property) ->
  array = []
  array[prop[property]] = prop for prop in source
  array

buildIndex types, 'name'
```

Result:

```
[Feature: Object, Enhancement: Object, Bug: Object, Spike: Object]
  Bug: Object
  Enhancement: Object
  Feature: Object
    name: "Feature" 
  Spike: Object
```

This is my ugly code.  How to refactor this?  My problem is the `buildIndex` function.  Iyt works, but  it isn't elegant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's something fishy here. You're creating an array, but you're not using it as one. You're simply adding named properties to it, like you can with any object. In the end, you're left with an array that still has a length of zero. So I'm betting you don't actually want an array at all.

And in that case, I'd rewrite it to this

```
buildIndex = (source, property) ->
  obj = {}
  obj[prop[property]] = prop for prop in source
  obj
```

No more array-nonsense. However, if this is indeed what you're going for, then that's pretty much it. I agree it doesn't look particularly elegant, but it's about as good as it gets with basic CoffeeScript.

However, you could use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), if you're targeting browsers that support it (or Node.js):

```
buildIndex = (source, property) ->
  source.reduce (obj, item) ->
    obj[item[property]] = item
    obj
  , {}
```

but as you can see, the callback-first style of `reduce` means you end up with a dangling comma and argument instead, which isn't terribly neat either.

Alternatively, if you're using something like [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org), you can use a `groupBy` function to do this for you

```
buildIndex = (source, property) ->
  _.groupBy source, (item) -> item[property]
```

Looks better, although it's merely hiding the same code as above.

Comment: Many thanks Flambino. underscore version is very elegant, but prefere use only coffescript ... replace array with object it's correct.